# Create in class validation code OR create a validation class?

Tags: c#, oop, exception

This is my first post, so I'm apologizing in advance for some mistakes, also english isn't my native language.
What is better and why? Keeping in mind I'm working with 2 other people and we'll have like 4 classes that will represent different types of person, and each class will have somewhere around 15 attributes.

A - Create a validation for each attribute of a class inside the same class:

```
public class People
{
    string name { get; set; }

    private void ValidateName()
    {
        if(this.name.Contains("0", ..., "9"))
            throw new Exception("Name can't contain numbers.");
    }
}
```

or B - Create a class (static class maybe?) for validation only:

```
public class People
{
    string name { get; set; }
}

static class Validation
{
    static void Name(string name)
    {
        if(name.Contains("0", ..., "9"))
            throw new Exception("Name can't contain numbers.")
    }
}

//and then somewhere in the code I call the Validation.Name(name) to verify if the code is ok.
```

Is there a third and more appropriate option? I don't even know if using Exceptions is the way to go.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to define what type of "better" you are looking for. For instance, better performance (speed or memory usage), better OO design for maintainability, or better for code simplicity?

Comment: Since it's a matter of preferences, I think your question would be best suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not SO.

Comment: There are a lot of options and opinions on this - unfortunately you've already accepted an answer so people won't be inclined to write further answers. FWIW I completely disagree with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third possible way is to use extension methods - I personaly like this, as it is as easy to use as the first one, but still seperates the logic:

```
public class Person
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class Validation
{
    public static void ValidateName(this Person person)
    {
        if(person.Name.Contains("0", ..., "9"))
            throw new Exception("Name can't contain numbers.")
    }
}
```

As mentioned this can be used like:

```
var person = new Person() { Name = "Test123" };
person.ValidateName();
```

P.S.: I renamed `People` to `Person` as it looks to me as it will hold one person and not multiple people - just ignore that if I am wrong on that...

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you sir, and as @Keith Payne said, I should have specify what i meant by "better". It was for maintainability.

Comment: How is separating the validation in this way improving maintainability? What advantage does putting it in an extension method have? You have validation behaviour which is tightly coupled to an entity, but now resides in a completely difference place. This violates the information expert principle.

Comment: When you think about 3 people working on that logic it CAN make sense. I did not say this is the best way, but he asked for another solution and I gave him a valid alternative. In my caseI do this, because I have a "Entities" project containing "stupid POCOs" and do the validation in another layer. Or another example from my code: I have a `LoadDefaults` extension and this is different depending on the actual case the base class is used...

Comment: Maybe your entities wouldn't be such "stupid pocos" if they took responsibility for enforcing their own class invariants.

Comment: You don't get my point: I DON'T want them to "take responsibility", because they are base classes which can be used in different contexts and the appropriate "mid layer" of each context takes care of that. The common validation (like "ID is required") is inside the POCO, but e.g. "e-mail required" not, because not every persons needs to have one...

Comment: aha! You've just mentioned the *real* reason to extract validation logic away from the entity... **context**. Any such validation is inherently tied to a *context* rather than the entity itself. For example, is this `Person` valid to save to the database? Is this `Person` valid to do some action on the website? Yes this contextual validation **should** be separated from the entity - in that case, again an extension method is not the correct mechanism because you are focusing on the entity and not on the context.

Comment: Then please tell me/us how it is done better - I am allways open for better solutions...

Comment: Looking at the original question, does it seem like contextual validation or a class invariant? I think it looks more like a class invariant... as you said *"The common validation (like "ID is required") is **inside the POCO**"* You already have the better solution :)

Comment: Thats the point: I don't know, as his example could be both (why should no user be allowed to contain numbers?), so I did not say my solution is the more appropriate one, but I told "*A third possible way is...*"...

Comment: This answer is fine. MattDavey is just being an ass.

Comment: Wow after all that I was really salivating waiting for the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your method to throw an error while instantiation in a constructor as shown below

```
public class People
    {
        string name { get; set; }

        public People(string n)
        {
            if (ValidateName(n))
            {
                this.name = n;
            }
        }

        private bool ValidateName(string n)
        {
            char[] nums = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
            if (n.IndexOfAny(nums) >= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Name can't contain numbers.");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

With the above code, the below will throw an exception.

```
People p = new People("x1asdf");
```

And this would be a successful instantiation

```
People p = new People("xasdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use property to validate data.

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    string Name { 
    get{return name;} 
    set
    {
        //Validation Logic
        if(name.Trim() == ""){throw new Exception("Invalid value for Name.");}
        //If all validation logic is ok then
        name = value;
    }
    }
}
```